# Getting terribly low accuracy when building my CNN for the mnist dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

As the title states, my CNN is getting terribly low accuracy on the mnist dataset (~70%). My architecture includes two convolution layers and two fully connected layers. I'm happy I've got it running but now i'm stumped on how I can optimize my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import urllib

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
  from urllib.request import urlretrieve
else:
  from urllib import urlretrieve

LOGDIR = 'log3/'
GITHUB_URL ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mamcgrath/TensorBoard-TF-Dev-Summit-Tutorial/master/'

### MNIST EMBEDDINGS ###
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.read_data_sets(train_dir=LOGDIR + 'data', one_hot=True)
### Get a sprite and labels file for the embedding projector ###
urlretrieve(GITHUB_URL + 'labels_1024.tsv', LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv')
urlretrieve(GITHUB_URL + 'sprite_1024.png', LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png')

# Add convolution layer
def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
  with tf.name_scope(name):
    #w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, size_in, size_out]), name="W")
    #b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_out]), name="B")
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 4, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
    act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
    return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")


# Add fully connected layer
def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
  with tf.name_scope(name):
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
    act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
    return act


def mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_conv, use_two_fc, hparam):
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  sess = tf.Session()

  # Setup placeholders, and reshape the data
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x")
  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
  tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="labels")

  if use_two_conv:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")
    conv_out = conv_layer(conv1, 32, 64, "conv2")
  else:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 64, "conv")
    conv_out = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

  flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])


  if use_two_fc:
    fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 7 * 7 * 64, 1024, "fc1")
    embedding_input = fc1
    embedding_size = 1024
    logits = fc_layer(fc1, 1024, 10, "fc2")
  else:
    embedding_input = flattened
    embedding_size = 7*7*64
    logits = fc_layer(flattened, 7*7*64, 10, "fc")

  with tf.name_scope("xent"):
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=y), name="xent")
    tf.summary.scalar("xent", xent)

  with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(xent)

  with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

  summ = tf.summary.merge_all()


  embedding = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024, embedding_size]), name="test_embedding")
  assignment = embedding.assign(embedding_input)
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR + hparam)
  writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

  config = tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.ProjectorConfig()
  embedding_config = config.embeddings.add()
  embedding_config.tensor_name = embedding.name
  embedding_config.sprite.image_path = LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png'
  embedding_config.metadata_path = LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv'
  # Specify the width and height of a single thumbnail.
  embedding_config.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([28, 28])
  tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)

  for i in range(201):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    if i % 5 == 0:
      [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
      writer.add_summary(s, i)
      print (train_accuracy)
    if i % 500 == 0:
      sess.run(assignment, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:1024], y: mnist.test.labels[:1024]})
      saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOGDIR, "model.ckpt"), i)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})

def make_hparam_string(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv):
  conv_param = "conv2" if use_two_conv else "conv1"
  fc_param = "fc2" if use_two_fc else "fc1"
  return "lr_%.0E%s%s" % (learning_rate, conv_param, fc_param)

def main():
  # You can try adding some more learning rates
  #for learning_rate in [1E-3, 1E-4, 1E-5]:
  for learning_rate in [1E-4]:

    # Include "False" as a value to try different model architectures
    #for use_two_fc in [True, False]:
    for use_two_fc in [True]:
      #for use_two_conv in [True, False]:
      for use_two_conv in [True]:
        # Construct a hyperparameter string for each one (example: "lr_1E-3fc2conv2")
        hparam = make_hparam_string(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv)
        print('Starting run for %s' % hparam)
        sys.stdout.flush() # this forces print-ed lines to show up.

        # Actually run with the new settings
        mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv, hparam)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Updated Code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import urllib

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
  from urllib.request import urlretrieve
else:
  from urllib import urlretrieve

LOGDIR = 'log3/'
GITHUB_URL ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mamcgrath/TensorBoard-TF-Dev-Summit-Tutorial/master/'

### MNIST EMBEDDINGS ###
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.read_data_sets(train_dir=LOGDIR + 'data', one_hot=True)
### Get a sprite and labels file for the embedding projector ###
urlretrieve(GITHUB_URL + 'labels_1024.tsv', LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv')
urlretrieve(GITHUB_URL + 'sprite_1024.png', LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png')

# Add convolution layer
def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
  with tf.name_scope(name):
    #w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, size_in, size_out]), name="W")
    #b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_out]), name="B")
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 4, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
    act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
    return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")


# Add fully connected layer
def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
  with tf.name_scope(name):
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
    act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
    return act


def mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_conv, use_two_fc, hparam):
  tf.set_random_seed(1)
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  sess = tf.Session()

  # Setup placeholders, and reshape the data
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x")
  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
  tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="labels")

  if use_two_conv:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")
    conv_out = conv_layer(conv1, 32, 64, "conv2")
  else:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 64, "conv")
    conv_out = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

  flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])


  if use_two_fc:
    fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 7 * 7 * 64, 40, "fc1")
    embedding_input = fc1
    embedding_size = 40
    logits = fc_layer(fc1, 40, 10, "fc2")
  else:
    embedding_input = flattened
    embedding_size = 40
    logits = fc_layer(flattened, 40, 10, "fc")

  with tf.name_scope("xent"):
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=y), name="xent")
    tf.summary.scalar("xent", xent)

  with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(xent)

  with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

  summ = tf.summary.merge_all()


  embedding = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, embedding_size]), name="test_embedding")
  assignment = embedding.assign(embedding_input)
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR + hparam)
  writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

  config = tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.ProjectorConfig()
  embedding_config = config.embeddings.add()
  embedding_config.tensor_name = embedding.name
  embedding_config.sprite.image_path = LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png'
  embedding_config.metadata_path = LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv'
  # Specify the width and height of a single thumbnail.
  embedding_config.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([28, 28])
  tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)

  for i in range(201):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(150)
    if i % 5 == 0:
      [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
      writer.add_summary(s, i)
      print (train_accuracy)
    #if i % 500 == 0:
      #sess.run(assignment, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:1024], y: mnist.test.labels[:1024]})
      #saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOGDIR, "model.ckpt"), i)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})

def make_hparam_string(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv):
  conv_param = "conv2" if use_two_conv else "conv1"
  fc_param = "fc2" if use_two_fc else "fc1"
  return "lr_%.0E%s%s" % (learning_rate, conv_param, fc_param)

def main():
  # You can try adding some more learning rates
  #for learning_rate in [1E-3, 1E-4, 1E-5]:
  for learning_rate in [0.002]:

    # Include "False" as a value to try different model architectures
    #for use_two_fc in [True, False]:
    for use_two_fc in [True]:
      #for use_two_conv in [True, False]:
      for use_two_conv in [True]:
        # Construct a hyperparameter string for each one (example: "lr_1E-3fc2conv2")
        hparam = make_hparam_string(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv)
        print('Starting run for %s' % hparam)
        sys.stdout.flush() # this forces print-ed lines to show up.

        # Actually run with the new settings
        mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv, hparam)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Updated results:

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
0.106667
0.213333
0.326667
0.426667
0.466667
0.473333
0.48
0.493333
0.506667
0.506667
0.473333
0.426667
0.46
0.46
0.506667
0.433333
0.526667
0.453333
0.506667
0.513333
0.42
0.426667
0.493333
0.486667
0.48
0.493333
0.5
0.493333
0.533333
0.433333
0.5
0.426667
0.42
0.493333
0.466667
0.466667
0.433333
0.46
0.52
0.513333
0.453333
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hidden layer is too large, so it is hard to train the network. I reduced its size from 1024 to 40, and modified the block inside the `if use_two_fc` statement as follows:

```
if use_two_fc:
    fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 7 * 7 * 64, 40, "fc1")
    embedding_input = fc1
    embedding_size = 40
    logits = fc_layer(fc1, 40, 10, "fc2")
```

Also I changed the learning rate to `0.002`. I increased the batch size to 150, so

```
batch = mnist.train.next_batch(150)
```

I also increased the number of iterations to 301. Finally, to make the results more consistent I added `tf.set_random_seed(1)` after the row

`tf.reset_default_graph()`. It increased the accuracy to 99%, as you can see in the list of accuracies that were printed:

```
Extracting log3/data\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting log3/data\train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting log3/data\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting log3/data\t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Starting run for lr_2E-03conv2fc2
0.133333
0.3
0.706667
0.693333
0.686667
0.726667
0.806667
0.84
0.893333
0.826667
0.846667
0.893333
0.893333
0.9
0.92
0.946667
0.893333
0.893333
0.966667
0.946667
0.946667
0.906667
0.946667
0.96
0.946667
0.966667
0.906667
0.946667
0.96
0.946667
0.92
0.96
0.953333
0.953333
0.933333
0.9
0.953333
0.966667
0.966667
0.986667
0.966667
0.986667
0.986667
0.933333
0.973333
0.973333
0.98
0.96
0.973333
0.973333
0.973333
0.986667
0.946667
0.966667
0.926667
0.94
0.96
0.973333
0.986667
0.993333
0.993333
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! When I make this change I get the following error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [40,40] rhs shape= [1024,40]`. This is odd as it runs fine for the first iteration then brings up this error.

Comment: Maybe you changed the 1024 to 40 in the line embedding = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024, embedding_size]), name="test_embedding")? This supposed to stay 1024 and not to be changed to 40.

Comment: In continuation to my previous comment, the 40 should appear only in the following three rows: fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 7 * 7 * 64, 40, "fc1")
 
,embedding_size = 40  and  logits = fc_layer(fc1, 40, 10, "fc2")

Comment: It was the `sess.run(assignment)` code that was causing this. It works now but my code only gets up to .80 within 200 iterations. I'll try more to see if I get closer to your values.

Comment: I've uploaded my updated file. Can you run that and see if it gets you the same results that you've shown above?

Comment: I think there is a lot of randomness in the initialization of the variables. To make it consistent, let's add the line tf.set_random_seed(1) right after tf.reset_default_graph() in your mnist_model function. This initialization produces high accuracy values.

Comment: Hm can you take a look at the edits I've made. I'm around 50% the last time around. This is with 201 iterations.

Comment: I also increased the number of iterations to 301, as it continues to improve the accuracy. The accuracy increased to 99% as you can see in my updated answer

Comment: You need to add tf.set_random_seed(1) after  tf.reset_default_graph() and not before. Otherwise it has no effect, as the graph is reset.

Comment: There you go, now i'm getting values 90+%. Can you explain what the random seed line and why that had such a big impact?

Comment: Whenever you initialize variables, if you do not specify the seed  they are initialized randomly, and results may be inconsistent. Once you set the seed, they will be initialized exactly to the same value every time you run the code, making the result consistent. Of course we could choose some other number and not 1 inside  tf.set_random_seed(1). I played a little with the values and found that 1 produces good accuracy.

Comment: Even without this line I got 96% accuracy as in my original answer, but this was a bit by chance and was hard to reproduce.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your help. I'll take a look at the documentation to learn more.